# Выпадающий список в зависимости от radio button?

Tags: yii2

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать:
Есть форма с одним полем($type), в ней должно быть 3 пункта( Radio Button) - Всем, Студентам, Группам.
Если выбрано всем, то ок (type = all), если выбрано студентам, то должен появляться dropdown со списком и уже выбранные студенты идут в $type = []) и тоже самое в группы.

Comment: я так понимаю это все должно работать без перезагрузки страницы? Если так, то надо подгружать список опций с помощью ajax, либо в момент загрузки страницы создать необходимые переменные и просто обновлять select из них

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем в один type добавлять и студентов и группы? В форме сделать три свойства. type, students, groups. На клиенте скрывать ненужный селект, в зависимости от выбора type, а на сервере принимать все данные, но обрабатывать в зависимости от выбора type. Так вроде бы логичнее и меньше путаницы будет.